# Problems starting X

Tags: raspbian, ssh, display, xorg

Just whacked Raspian on an SD card, and booted up my Pi.

A message at the top says 'Use `startx` to start a graphical interface'.

So I `startx`.

I get a load of details: OS version; X version; all that lot.

And then it stops. The program doesn't close, it just sits there, as if it's working something out or something.

This nothing-happening-state stays there seemingly, forever.

I'm running Raspbian, and accessing the Pi through SSH on a Windows machine.

I assume the problem is something to do with SSH, as surely the recommended distro wouldn't normally fail when accessing a common, advertised command?

So how do I launch X when using SSH?

**Update - Xorg log**

**Warnings and errors, in order they were found**

```
[  2212.985] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc" does not exist.
[  2212.985]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2212.985] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[  2212.985]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2212.985] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[  2212.986]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2212.986] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[  2212.986]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2212.986] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1" does not exist.
[  2212.986]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2212.986] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[  2212.987]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2212.987] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[  2212.987]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2212.987] (WW) The directory "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType" does not exist.
[  2212.987]    Entry deleted from font path.
```

```
[  2213.033] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
```

```
[  2213.038] (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
```

```
[  2213.054] (EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Operation not permitted
```

```
[  2213.169] (EE) AIGLX error: dlopen of /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
[  2213.169] (EE) GLX: could not load software renderer
[  2213.170] (II) GLX: no usable GL providers found for screen 0
[  2213.556] (EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Operation not permitted
```

**Full log**

```
[  2212.941] _XSERVTransSocketOpenCOTSServer: Unable to open socket for inet6
[  2212.942] _XSERVTransOpen: transport open failed for inet6/raspberrypi:0
[  2212.942] _XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: failed to open listener for inet6
[  2212.952] 
X.Org X Server 1.12.1.902 (1.12.2 RC 2)
Release Date: 2012-05-19
[  2212.957] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[  2212.959] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-2-mx5 armv7l Debian
[  2212.959] Current Operating System: Linux raspberrypi 3.1.9+ #168 PREEMPT Sat Jul 14 18:56:31 BST 2012 armv6l
[  2212.961] Kernel command line: dma.dmachans=0x3c bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=656 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=416 bcm2708.boardrev=0x2 bcm2708.serial=0xe42c17c8 smsc95xx.macaddr=B8:27:EB:2C:17:C8 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait
[  2212.965] Build Date: 27 May 2012  02:13:12PM
[  2212.966] xorg-server 2:1.12.1.902-1 (Cyril Brulebois ) 
[  2212.967] Current version of pixman: 0.26.0
[  2212.968]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[  2212.969] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[  2212.975] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sun Jul 29 09:45:48 2012
[  2212.978] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  2212.980] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[  2212.981] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[  2212.981] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[  2212.981] (**) |   |-->Monitor ""
[  2212.984] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[  2212.984] (==) Automatically adding devices
[  2212.984] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[  2212.985] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc" does not exist.
[  2212.985]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2212.985] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[  2212.985]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2212.985] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[  2212.986]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2212.986] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[  2212.986]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2212.986] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1" does not exist.
[  2212.986]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2212.986] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[  2212.987]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2212.987] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[  2212.987]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2212.987] (WW) The directory "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType" does not exist.
[  2212.987]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2212.987] (==) FontPath set to:
    built-ins
[  2212.988] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[  2212.988] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[  2212.988] (II) Loader magic: 0x401bbcf0
[  2212.988] (II) Module ABI versions:
[  2212.988]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[  2212.989]    X.Org Video Driver: 12.0
[  2212.989]    X.Org XInput driver : 16.0
[  2212.989]    X.Org Server Extension : 6.0
[  2212.989] (II) LoadModule: "extmod"
[  2212.992] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libextmod.so
[  2212.997] (II) Module extmod: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2212.997]    compiled for 1.12.1.902, module version = 1.0.0
[  2212.997]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[  2212.998]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[  2212.998] (II) Loading extension SELinux
[  2212.998] (II) Loading extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[  2212.998] (II) Loading extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[  2212.998] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DGA
[  2212.998] (II) Loading extension DPMS
[  2212.999] (II) Loading extension XVideo
[  2212.999] (II) Loading extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[  2212.999] (II) Loading extension X-Resource
[  2212.999] (II) LoadModule: "dbe"
[  2213.001] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdbe.so
[  2213.003] (II) Module dbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2213.003]    compiled for 1.12.1.902, module version = 1.0.0
[  2213.003]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[  2213.003]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[  2213.004] (II) Loading extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[  2213.004] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  2213.005] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[  2213.007] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2213.007]    compiled for 1.12.1.902, module version = 1.0.0
[  2213.007]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[  2213.008] (==) AIGLX enabled
[  2213.008] (II) Loading extension GLX
[  2213.008] (II) LoadModule: "record"
[  2213.010] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/librecord.so
[  2213.012] (II) Module record: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2213.012]    compiled for 1.12.1.902, module version = 1.13.0
[  2213.012]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[  2213.012]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[  2213.012] (II) Loading extension RECORD
[  2213.013] (II) LoadModule: "dri"
[  2213.014] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri.so
[  2213.016] (II) Module dri: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2213.017]    compiled for 1.12.1.902, module version = 1.0.0
[  2213.017]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[  2213.017] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DRI
[  2213.017] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[  2213.019] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
[  2213.020] (II) Module dri2: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2213.021]    compiled for 1.12.1.902, module version = 1.2.0
[  2213.021]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[  2213.021] (II) Loading extension DRI2
[  2213.021] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 0
[  2213.022] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[  2213.022] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[  2213.024] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[  2213.025] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2213.025]    compiled for 1.12.1, module version = 0.4.2
[  2213.025]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 12.0
[  2213.025] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[  2213.026] (--) using VT number 7

[  2213.033] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[  2213.033] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[  2213.033] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[  2213.035] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[  2213.037] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2213.037]    compiled for 1.12.1.902, module version = 0.0.2
[  2213.037]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 12.0
[  2213.038] (II) FBDEV(0): using default device
[  2213.038] (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
[  2213.039] (II) FBDEV(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 16/16
[  2213.039] (==) FBDEV(0): Depth 16, (==) framebuffer bpp 16
[  2213.039] (==) FBDEV(0): RGB weight 565
[  2213.039] (==) FBDEV(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[  2213.043] (==) FBDEV(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[  2213.043] (II) FBDEV(0): hardware: BCM2708 FB (video memory: 533kB)
[  2213.044] (II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against framebuffer device...
[  2213.044] (II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against monitor...
[  2213.044] (--) FBDEV(0): Virtual size is 656x416 (pitch 656)
[  2213.044] (**) FBDEV(0):  Built-in mode "current"
[  2213.045] (==) FBDEV(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[  2213.045] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[  2213.045] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[  2213.047] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[  2213.048] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2213.049]    compiled for 1.12.1.902, module version = 1.0.0
[  2213.049]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[  2213.049] (**) FBDEV(0): using shadow framebuffer
[  2213.049] (II) Loading sub module "shadow"
[  2213.049] (II) LoadModule: "shadow"
[  2213.051] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libshadow.so
[  2213.053] (II) Module shadow: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2213.053]    compiled for 1.12.1.902, module version = 1.1.0
[  2213.053]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[  2213.054] (EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Operation not permitted
[  2213.056] (==) FBDEV(0): Backing store disabled
[  2213.057] (==) FBDEV(0): DPMS enabled
[  2213.058] (==) RandR enabled
[  2213.058] (II) Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[  2213.058] (II) Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[  2213.059] (II) Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[  2213.059] (II) Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[  2213.059] (II) Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[  2213.059] (II) Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[  2213.059] (II) Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[  2213.059] (II) Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[  2213.060] (II) Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[  2213.060] (II) Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[  2213.060] (II) Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[  2213.060] (II) Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[  2213.060] (II) Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[  2213.061] (II) Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[  2213.061] (II) Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[  2213.061] (II) Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[  2213.061] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[  2213.168] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable
[  2213.169] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI capable
[  2213.169] (EE) AIGLX error: dlopen of /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
[  2213.169] (EE) GLX: could not load software renderer
[  2213.170] (II) GLX: no usable GL providers found for screen 0
[  2213.556] (EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Operation not permitted
[  2216.149] Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

**Xsession-errors** (this one error is repeated for every time I try and run X)

```
Xsession: X session started for pi at Sun Jul 29 10:26:05 UTC 2012
Obt-Message: Xinerama extension is not present on the server
Openbox-Message: Unable to find a valid menu file "/usr/share/lxde/openbox/menu.xml"
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
  after 1995 requests (1995 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
pcmanfm: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
```

Comment: Do you have a monitor/TV connected to your Raspberry PI?

Comment: @asalamon74 no, it's all through SSH, keyboard, screen, the lot.

Comment: You're going to need to do tunnel-forwarding via SSH to make this work.

Comment: Post your Xorg log.

Comment: @Haskeller have done, and also added all the errors and warnings in a separate place.

Comment: @ACarter Did you post both ~/.xsession-errors and /var/log/Xorg.0.log ?

Comment: Keyboard or screen can't be connected (normally) through ssh. It's a whole different session through a network connection.

Comment: It's sad that after 6 years, all those same messages are still present in the most current *Stretch*. Still people in the community keep saying, just ignore it! These kind of annoyances need to be fixed!

Comment: @not2qubit: About missing fonts, cyrillic and so on? These messages are at least 20 years old!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That display of information you see is `Xorg` starting up. The reason is starts but doesn't show anything is because there is no graphical output connected to the Pi, such as a monitor or TV. Thus `Xorg` doesn't know how to handle the `XSession`.

There are a few possible solutions, depending on what you are trying to achieve.

- If you have a screen connected to the Pi then the command will do the same, but output will appear on the screen. If you run `startx &` then `x` will start in the background and you can carrying on running commands in the `ssh` terminal like normal.
- Since you are using Windows, if you want your `Xsession` to be displayed on the client then you will have an `X` server installed and then forward the `X` session over ssh. This can be achieved with [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes) and Putty. You can find some useful information about setting this up [here](http://www.math.umn.edu/systems_guide/putty_xwin32.html).
- If you have a machine running Linux with `Xorg` installed then you can easily forward the `X` session. This [excellent Unix & Linux Stack Exchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12772) will teach you how.

Hope this helps, let me know if there are any other factors that I haven't covered.

Comment: Nothing you haven't covered, it just doesn't work for me. (second option) I have Xming running, but when I `startx` I just end up in the same place, a load of details on the screen and nothing happening.

Comment: Come for a [chat] and I'll try and help more.

Comment: Right, the issue has magically fixed, but I'm accepting you're answer because it works with Xming, and I hadn't heard about that before you said. Thanks :)

Comment: @Jivings is solution #3 possible via Max OS X? Following that Linux SE answer seems to only produce the result of solution #1.

Comment: @McKAMEY I can't say I've tried it, but I don't see why not.

Answer (score 4):

Going off of this quote from your question "I'm running Raspbian, and accessing the Pi through SSH on a Windows machine." it sounds like you're approaching the whole GUI desktop access problem the hard way around.  There are ways to forward an xsession over ssh but its a bit complicated and you're adding the extra complication running Windows as well.  A better solution would be to [run VNC server on the Raspberry Pi](http://elinux.org/RPi_VNC_Server) and [VNC client on your Windows computer](http://www.realvnc.com/download/viewer/).

There are lots of VNC clients available I just posted the first one to show up in google.  Using VNC will give you basically a cross platform remote desktop experience which sounds like what you're looking for.

Just to be up front and honest this VNC solution assumes that X did actually start but you didn't get a GUI because you're using plain old ssh with Putty.

So to recap:

1. Use Putty to access the Raspberry Pi over ssh like you're currently doing and follow the directions to [set up VNC Server](http://elinux.org/RPi_VNC_Server).
2. Set up some VNC client on your Windows computer (use my link or google for this as there are lots of them).
3. You can stop using Putty now and instead fire up your newly installed VNC client and use that to access your Pi with a full GUI desktop.

Answer (score 2):

It seems your drivers are corrupted or not installed.
I haven't tried these since I don't use Raspian.

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install xorg xutils xserver-xorg xterm xserver-xorg-video-fbdev xserver-xorg-video-vesa
```

You might also have to reconfigure [Xorg.conf](http://www.x.org/wiki/ConfigurationHelp/#Xorg_-configure)

```
Xorg -configure
```

Copy it to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and `vi /etc/X11/xorg.conf` or `nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Fonts:

```
apt-get install ttf-dejavu
```

Comment: This doesn't address the fact that there is no screen for the session.

Answer (score 0):

When running from a Windows machine I found MobaXterm made life incredibly easy.
It has both terminal and graphic capabilities as well as a SFTP file access window.